# Unable to backup Postgres Database, pg_dump fails on EXECUTE dumpBaseType as it returns zero rows

Tags: postgresql, backup

I have a Postgres database running in a docker container, from the famous Teslamate project. All in all, the whole solution works just fine.
But as the data I collect gets more and more valuable, I get more and more worried on losing it. So a backup is a good idea.
However, when I try to create a back in my container (postgres-database) I get this:

docker compose exec -T postgres-database pg_dump -U teslamate teslamate > /root/teslamate.bck
pg_dump: error: query returned 0 rows instead of one: EXECUTE dumpBaseType('24686')

I have asked in the Teslamate community, but nobody has come across this before and no one seems to know enough about Postgres to really say what is happening.

I have tried instead starting a shell inside the container, running pg_dump there, but same result.
Looked a bit at the Postgres source code for pg_dump, but can't get wise on why it is not returning any rows.
Googled like crazy, but it only seems to be me who gets this error.

So, any Postgres wizards out there, who might know why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

You have a corrupted database.

Somewhere in your system catalogs, something (a table column? a function parameter? could be anything) refers to the data type with object ID 24686, but there is no such type in `pg_type`. Does the error message give you any context, so that you can figure out where that data type is referenced?

The simple solution is to restore your latest good database backup.
Other than that, you can figure out where the data type is referenced and drop or repair that object.

Did you manipulate catalog tables directly? Did you install any non-standard extensions?